# Wildcard ssl certificate made website slow

Tags: ssl, nginx, digital-ocean, certbot

I have ubuntu 18.04 LT, server with `nginx` installed and ssl certificate generated with `certbot`. Every `https://` request takes too much time and return fails.

**This site can’t be reached** *took too long to respond*'

in **chrome** and when refresh it loads again.
this is my `nginx` config file.
***/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com***

```
server {

    root /var/www/mysite.com/app;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mysite.com *.mysite.me;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot # mysite.com-0001/privkey.pem
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0001/fullchain.pem; 
    # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0001/privkey.pem; 
    # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Do the logs say anything? Might be a ServerFault question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. The OP has already [asked it at serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/928743/wildcard-ssl-certificate-made-website-slow) where it is probably more on-topic.

Comment: And it has been also removed from [sf] because of moderation...